# Firefox has problems when downloading with a space in filename

Tags: php, firefox, filenames

It seems that firefox has a problem with spaces within the filename for downloading...

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputs($fp, $csvdata);
fclose($fp);
```

Here is an example of a file named: `Test_ Grad Fair 2_20140129_1312_607.csv`

When I attempt to download the file using the code above with FireFox the following occurs. (the main problem is it removes the file extension!)

[image: Download Image from Firefox]

And when I try downloading it from Safari, or Chrome:

[image: Downloading it from Safari]

I know a solution would be to maybe do something like:

```
$filename = str_replace(' ', '', $filename);
```

However, I prefer to figure out why FireFox is having this problem, it seems kinda ridiculous that you can't have a space in a filename. Could this be like a `%20` instead of a space problem?

Comment: Spaces in file names that are going to be hosted online are generally A Bad Idea. It will be much, _much_ easier to rename your files than to wait for Firefox not to have this problem.

Comment: Did you actually try `%20` or `+`? Or `urlencode()`?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall if my clients have uploaded a file and want to download it using the original filename is really the best option. It would be really strange to cause an inconvenience to my website users from such a technical problem if there is a solution.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The filename parameter should be enclosed in double quotes.

```
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filenames_with_spaces_are_truncated_upon_download

Comment: It still helping today! kkk

Comment: You are awesome, literally saved me a day. +1

Answer (score 2):

I had a small issue while downloading a file with file name contains space. 
I fixed this issue using the following code. 
I had written this code for CodeIgniter frame work.

```
    $file_name = 'Test Pdf.pdf'; //Your file name
    $original_file_name = 'Test Pdf.pdf'; //Your file name
    $file_name = str_replace(' ', '%20', $file_name);
    $file_url = asset_url("uploads/agent_logo/46/".$file_name);// Full file path including file name.
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $original_file_name . "\"");
    readfile($file_url);
```

This will work for all type of files and all browsers including mozilla firefox and IE