# Downloading Blobs from TrueVault with spaces in the filename

Tags: php, rest, truevault

I'm using the TrueVault REST API to upload/download Blobs per the documentation at https://docs.truevault.com/Files

To download an existing Blob, I'm passing the Blob URL directly to the client's web browser (Firefox) via a PHP Header redirect.  The client is able to download the Blob content from TrueVault without issue, but when using Firefox I've noticed that if the Blob being downloaded has spaces in the filename, the filename is truncated when downloading.

For instance, if I upload a Blob to TrueVault with filename 'Test File.txt', it gets downloaded to Firefox as just 'Test'.  I've seen this behavior in other PHP apps and the fix has been to put quotes around the filename in the Response Headers, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21443015/4846920).

I've traced the Response Headers from TrueVault when downloading and I can see where the filename is being passed to the client without any quotes around the name. Since the client is downloading the Blob directly from TrueVault, there's nothing I can do in my code to affect this behavior. Anyone else seeing this behavior? Any suggestions?

```
Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=31536000
Server: gunicorn/18.0
Date:   Wed, 29 Apr 2015 14:40:28 GMT
Content-Type:   application/zip
Content-Length: 11377
Content-Disposition:    attachment; filename=Test file with Spaces.docx
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control:  no-cache
```

Comment: We’ve deployed the fix for this on our end and you should notice that the full filename is present upon download.

Answer (score 1):

This issue will be addressed by 4/30/2015. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.